# Shell, behavior of conflicting redirection

Tags: shell, redirect

I'm facing to a problem that I'm not able to explain. I've to recode a shell, and there is a weird behavior for me.

`echo test >&2 2>&1`

This kind of command is writing on stderr (so with the first redirection), why the second redirection isn't impacting the output destination ? Why the output isn't on stdout ?

I saw some stuff that redirection is happening before executing command, from left to right, so why the second redirection is not cancelling the first one ?

Thanks in advance.

edit: I'm running my script on bash.

Comment: [BashFAQ #55](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055) (*Tell me all about `2>&1` -- what's the difference between `2>&1 >foo` and `>foo 2>&1`, and when do I use which?*) is pertinent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd >&2 2>&1` is very different than `cmd 2>&1 >&2`, since the redirections occur in a different order.  Suppose the command is invoked from a process which has fd 1 attached to a file named 'output' and fd 2 attached to a filed named 'error'.  Then `cmd >&2 2>&1` will redirect the stdout of `cmd` to the file named `error` and then redirect stderr of `cmd` to whatever fd 1 is connected to, namely the file named `error`.  But `cmd 2>&1 >&2` will first redirect fd 2 to 'output' and the redirect fd 1 to the same place.  In other words, `cmd >&2 2>&1` writes everything to stderr, and `cmd 2>&1 >&2` writes everything on stdout.

Answer (score 2):

`x>&y` means "redirect file descriptor x to *whatever fd y is **currently** pointing to*.
Redirections are processed strictly left to right.

So, `>&2 2>&1` points fd 1 to something like /dev/stderr, and then points fd 2 to /dev/stderr also.

If you want to **swap** stderr and stdout, you need a 3rd file descriptor:

```
(echo "test to stdout"; echo "test to stderr" >&2) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-
# ................................................ A .. B .. C .. D
# A. fd 3 = /dev/stdout
# B. fd 1 = /dev/stderr
# C. fd 2 = /dev/stdout
# D. fd 3 is closed
```

Let's put that in a function for easier testing

```
fdtest() { (echo "test to stdout"; echo "test to stderr" >&2) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-; }
```

Run it

```
$ fdtest
test to stdout
test to stderr
```

Throw away standard error (we expect to see the "stderr" message on standard out).

```
$ fdtest 2>/dev/null
test to stderr
```

Throw away standard out (we expect to see the "stdout" message on standard err).

```
$ fdtest 1>/dev/null
test to stdout
```